# Refresh RDD LKP Table Via Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming application that is pulling data from a kafka topic and then correlating that data with a dimensional lookup In spark.  While I have managed to load in the dimensional lookup table from hive on the first run into an RDD; I want this dimensional lkp rdd to be refreshed every one hour.

From my understanding SparkStreaming is effectively a spark scheduler, I am wondering if its possible to create a JavaDStream of the Dimensional lookup RDD, and have it refresh on a scheduled interval using Spark Streaming.  The problem is I have no idea how to approach this, from my understanding an RDD is immutable, meaning is it even possible to refresh a JavaDStream in spark and join it with JavaDStream that is running on a different schedule?

Current Code:

```
    System.out.println("Loading from Hive Tables...");

//Retrieve Dimensional LKP data from hive table into RDD (CombineIVAPP function retrieves the data from Hive and performs initial joins)
final JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<modelService,modelONT>> LKP_IVAPP_DIM = CombineIVAPP();
LKP_IVAPP_DIM.cache();

System.out.println("Mapped Tables to K/V Pairs");

    //Kafka Topic settings
    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicMap.put(KAFKA_TOPIC,KAFKA_PARA);

    //Begin to stream from Kafka Topic
    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(
            jssc, ZOOKEEPER_URL, KAFKA_GROUPID, topicMap);


    //Map messages from Kafka Stream to Tuple
    JavaDStream<String> json = messages.map(
            new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Tuple2<String, String> message) {
                    return message._2();
                }
            }
    );

    //Map kafka JSON string to K/V RDD
    JavaPairDStream<String, modelAlarms> RDD_ALARMS = json.mapToPair(new KafkaToRDD());

    //Remove the null values
    JavaPairDStream<String, modelAlarms> RDD_ALARMS_FILTERED = RDD_ALARMS.filter(new Function<Tuple2<String, modelAlarms>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Tuple2<String, modelAlarms> item) {
                    return item != null;
                }
            });

    //Join Alarm data from Kafka topic with hive lkp table LKP_IVAPP_DIM
    JavaPairDStream<String, Tuple2<modelAlarms,Tuple2<modelService,modelONT>>> RDD_ALARMS_JOINED = RDD_ALARMS_FILTERED.transformToPair(new Function<JavaPairRDD<String, modelAlarms>, JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<modelAlarms, Tuple2<modelService,modelONT>>>>() {
        @Override
        public JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<modelAlarms, Tuple2<modelService,modelONT>>> call(JavaPairRDD<String, modelAlarms> v1) throws Exception {
            return v1.join(LKP_IVAPP_DIM);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think this should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638519/spark-streaming-how-to-periodically-refresh-cached-rdd/37653261#37653261

Comment: I checked out your answer first....quick question about that.  When you create an empty ConstantInputDStream with empty data, the problem is I have no idea what the Seq() is supposed to represent.  Is it possible to replace that with an Empty RDD instead?

Comment: Line I am referring to is this one // a dstream of empty data
val refreshDstream = new  ConstantInputDStream(ssc, sparkContext.parallelize(Seq())).window(Seconds(refreshInterval),Seconds(refreshInterval))

Comment: yes, you can use `EmptyRDD` for that.