# Load External RDD Periodically during Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I have a separate rdd that needs to be refreshed periodically in my spark streaming job. There has been some solutions proposed (i.e. [Spark Streaming: How to periodically refresh cached RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638519/spark-streaming-how-to-periodically-refresh-cached-rdd)), however they all involve reconstructing the rdd in a `stream.foreachRDD()` loop. This will create a `spark context not serializable error` for me as I need to create my rdd with an `sc.parallelize()` method

In other words, I can't do `sc.parallelize()` inside a `foreachRDD()` loop. Any advice on alternative ways to approach this?